# Possible without using 'It is'

Tags: word-choice

Can you use "possible" without "it's" in a sentence like:
"So you think it's the White House. Possible..." Or do you have to say: "So you think it's the White House. Possibly...."

Comment: Yes, in colloquial speech a single word can be used to stand for a brief sentence, if that's what you were asking (it's unclear because of your use of suspension points).

Comment: "*That* is possible."

Comment: That's indeed what I was asking. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @KateBunting You can make that comment an answer. In general please don't write answers in comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, in colloquial speech a single word may be made to stand for a short sentence such as 'It is possible'.

Comment: Please could you elaborate? This is in the low-quality review queue.

Comment: I only made my comment into an answer because @DJClayworth asked me to.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that from the queue. Also, not my downvote. I guess an example from the wild would make it better